# webViewSettings setLayoutAlgorithm LayoutAlgorithm NORMAL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

`webView.getsettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL)` causes problems when I rebind the html content by using JavaScript or Jquery, i.e.: Some table contents go missing.

Initially, my html table is not rendering properly. That is why I opted `webView.getsettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL)` to render my html tables properly. Actually, I am using a css3 column property to bind my contents in `WebView`.

Comment: First you say that your html table is not rendering properly, but at the end you say you are using css3 columns, which is something completely different. So which is it? Are you using tables, or css3 columns, or both? It might be helpful if you provided an example of the actual markup that is not rendering properly.